# Akka Dispatcher Dying

Tags: scala, akka, actor, dispatcher

I've got a service that monitors an entire subnet to search for devices being plugged in. When it finds a new device, it'll provision it and update the device's firmware and reboot it... That all works fine. My issue is that according to my logs, the dispatcher seems to be having some issues.

```
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.509] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65329] [akka://default/user/$Db] Updating 192.168.4.163
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.510] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65342] [akka://default/user/$Nb] Updating 192.168.4.153
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.514] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65342] [akka://default/user/$p] Updating 192.168.4.241
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.515] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65345] [akka://default/user/$2b] Updating 192.168.4.138
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.516] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$r] Updating 192.168.4.239
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.518] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65341] [akka://default/user/$kb] Updating 192.168.4.182
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.518] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$hb] Updating 192.168.4.185
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.520] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65344] [akka://default/user/$ec] Updating 192.168.4.124
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.521] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65343] [akka://default/user/$Zb] Updating 192.168.4.141
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.797] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65342] [akka://default/user/$Sb] Updating 192.168.4.148
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:46.882] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$Gb] Updating 192.168.4.160
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:47.123] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$Yb] Updating 192.168.4.142
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.065] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$s] Updating 192.168.4.238
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.184] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65341] [akka://default/user/$Xb] Updating 192.168.4.143
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.514] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65341] [akka://default/user/$Db] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.163
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.514] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65343] [akka://default/user/$Nb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.153
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.613] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$p] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.241
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.615] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$2b] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.138
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.615] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65344] [akka://default/user/$kb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.182
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.615] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$r] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.239
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.615] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65344] [akka://default/user/$ec] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.124
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.616] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65329] [akka://default/user/$hb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.185
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.616] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65344] [akka://default/user/$Zb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.141
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.813] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$Sb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.148
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.914] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65341] [akka://default/user/$Gb] Requesting sid from 192.168.4.160
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:48.921] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65345] [akka://default/user/$Nb] Provisioning 192.168.4.153
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.009] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65345] [akka://default/user/$hb] Provisioning 192.168.4.185
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.012] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65345] [akka://default/user/$kb] Provisioning 192.168.4.182
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.015] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65343] [akka://default/user/$ec] Provisioning 192.168.4.124
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.016] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65341] [akka://default/user/$r] Provisioning 192.168.4.239
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.052] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65328] [akka://default/user/$2b] Provisioning 192.168.4.138
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.053] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65343] [akka://default/user/$p] Provisioning 192.168.4.241    
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.099] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65343] [akka://default/user/$Zb] Provisioning 192.168.4.141
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.108] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$Nb] Rebooting 192.168.4.153
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.185] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$hb] Rebooting 192.168.4.185
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.190] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65345] [akka://default/user/$r] Rebooting 192.168.4.239
[INFO] [12/23/2014 09:54:49.191] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-65347] [akka://default/user/$kb] Rebooting 192.168.4.182
```

The dispatcher-xxxxx keeps going up the longer the program runs. This is after roughly a week of runtime, and (if my instincts are correct) akka has had to remake over 65k of the same dispatcher.

What is something that causes this? I've never seen this on other applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing there is actually the thread id of the thread that is running that task on behalf of the dispatcher.  This does not mean that you have 65K dispatchers.  I think the implication is that it is growing and shrinking the thread pool as needed, and the new threads get a continually increasing number.  I don't think this is an issue.